# Помогите решить олимпиадную задачу по информатике про клетки на шахматной доске

Tags: python, олимпиада

Условие: Шахматная доска состоит из n×m клеток, покрашенных в чёрный и белый цвет в шахматном порядке. При этом клетка в левом нижнем углу доски покрашена в чёрный цвет. Определите, сколько всего на доске чёрных клеток.
Программа получает на вход натуральные числа n и m. Программа должна вывести ответ на задачу.
Например:
3
4
Вывод: 6
Пробовал разные доски на бумаге: получалась всегда половина черных и белых

```
n, m = int(input()), int(input())
print(n * m / 2)
```

такой код не принимает.

Comment: А на доске 5 на 5? 12.5 черных клеток?

Comment: А на доске 1 на 1?

Answer (score 4):

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
print((n * m + 1) // 2)
```

спасибо за комментарии, с нечет * нечет я почему-то не проверил

Answer (score 1):

В одном случае число белых и черных будет отличатся - когда n и m нечетные.
Для всех остальных случаев простое деление на 2 даст искомый ответ.

```
3 x 3 = 9

x 0 x
0 x 0
x 0 x

5 - черных, 4 белых
```

То есть, ответ на вашу задачу - после деления на 2 округлить к большему.